# Can these asymptotic conditional expectations be bounded from above?

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, asymptotics

**Problem Setup**

Let $\{X^d_1, X^d_2, \cdots, X^d_n\}$ be a $d-$dimensional zero-mean, i.i.d. random variables. Let $S_n^d$ be 
$$
S^d_n = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^d}{\sqrt{n}}
$$

Let $Y^d$ be a zero-mean normal random variable with covariance $\Sigma^d = \mathbb{E}\big[X^d(X^d)^T\big]$

The paper by [Bentkus](http://www.mii.lt/files/Bentkus_2003_2.pdf), for a given class $\mathcal{A}$, has the following result:

> $$
> \sup_{A\in \mathcal{A}} \big|\mathbb{P}\{S^d_n\in A\}−\mathbb{P}\{Y^d\in A\}\big|\leq  \frac{c_d(\mathcal{A})\beta}{\sqrt{n}}; \qquad  \beta = \mathbb{E}\big[|X^d|^3\big]
> $$
>
> - The constant $c_d(\mathcal{A}) = d^{1/4}$ when $\mathcal{A}$ is
>     all the convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and
> - $c_d(\mathcal{A}) = 1 $
>     when $\mathcal{A}$ is all the Euclidian balls in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

**Question**
Can we upperbound any of the following when $d$ grows with $n$?

1. $\Big|\mathbb{E}\big[S^d_n \big] - \mathbb{E}\big[Y^d\big]\Big|$
2. $\Big|\mathbb{E}\big[S^d_n(i)\big\vert S^d_n(1,2,\cdots,i-1) \big] - \mathbb{E}\big[Y^d(i)\big\vert Y^d(1,2,\cdots,i-1)\big]\Big|$

Here $S^d_n(i)$ is the $i^{th}$ component $d-$dimensional vector and $S^d_n(1,2,\cdots,i-1)$ are the first the $(i-1)$ components of $S^d_n$.

**Possible Method**

I have a method which might possibly give some upper-bound but I am unsure of this idea and it requires some nuanced arguments (which I am unable to make).
$$\Big|\mathbb{E}\big[S^d_n \big] - \mathbb{E}\big[Y^d\big]\Big| = \int_{x\in\mathbb{R}^d}x\Big(p_S(x) - p_Y(x)\Big)dx \\
\leq \sqrt{\int_{x\in\mathbb{R}^d}x^2\big|p_S(x) - p_Y(x)\big|dx \int_{x\in\mathbb{R}^d}\big|p_S(x) - p_Y(x)\big|dx }\\
\leq \sqrt{\int_{x\in\mathbb{R}^d}x^2\big(p_S(x) + p_Y(x)\big)dx \int_{x\in\mathbb{R}^d}\big|p_S(x) - p_Y(x)\big|dx } \\
\leq \sqrt{2d\sigma^2\int_{x\in\mathbb{R}^d}\big|p_S(x) - p_Y(x)\big|dx } \\ 
\overset{?}{\leq} \sqrt{2d\sigma^2\frac{2c_d(\mathcal{A})\beta}{\sqrt{n}}} \\ 
$$

**Issues:**

1. I am not sure the conditions under which the last equation is valid.
2. In the above method I am using the Lebesgue measure, can we get better bounds using other measures? (Note : $c_d(\mathcal{A}) = 1 $
   when $\mathcal{A}$ is all the Euclidean balls in $\mathbb{R}^d$.)
3. How can one apply similar ideas for question 2?

Comment: The above problem might not be well posed, feel free to edit the question if that improves the question.

Comment: Are $S_n$ and $Y$ in the $\sup$ inequality the same as $S_n^d$ and Y^d$?

Comment: The last step is correct but useless because $\int\big|p_S(x)-p_Y(x)\big|dx$ is total variation distance and it takes supremum over class of all sets. However $c_d(\mathcal{A})$ is bounded only when the $\mathcal{A}$ is set of convex set or Euclidean balls.